# MySQL how to make a letter equals another letter when SELECT?

Tags: mysql

I speak a language that has 2 letters that are very similar, and people mix up the 2 letters all the time.

Is there a way to make 1 letter equals another when "SELECT"?

For Example I've got this table:

```
Name     id     Col1      Col2
Row1     1      Corn      4
Row2     2      Cheese    4
Row3     3      Bread     4
Row4     4      Meat      4
```

When the user search for the ID of the word "**Corn**" or "**Korn**" the ID that must come up is "**1**"

So I want the letter "**K**" to equal the letter "**C**".

Hopefully this is clear. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with [SOUNDS LIKE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778252/php-mysql-highlight-sounds-like-query-results)?

Comment: @MarkBaker i'v tried it, didn't work the way i want it.

Comment: eventually you could use replace .. i

Comment: Could you use `WHERE \`Col1\`='Corn' OR \`Col1\`='Korn'`?

Comment: Well perhaps consider something as simple as `WHERE Col1 = 'CORN' or Col1 = 'Korn'`; but computers don't do magic, or understand human beings; they're just objects that do what they're told to do

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SOUNDEX(Col1)=SOUNDEX('Korn') ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL SOUNDS LIKE operator and it will do the trick. Otherwise it seems there is no chance unless you develop your own algorithm.

ex

```
SELECT * FROM student 
WHERE col1 SOUNDS LIKE 'corn'
```